# what is the difference between user, profile and roles

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

What is the differences between roles, profile and users in SQL Plus?

Comment: Why was this question closed? A thorough understanding of user roles in Oracle is very important for a good application design and implementation. Without access privileges (which can be bundled in roles), no application can read or write any data!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle's concept guide is an very good starting point for such questions.

See for example [user accounts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/topics-for-database-administrators-and-developers.html#GUID-CE700CE1-BF1B-48C0-A905-50CEE055C4BC), profiles and roles just after that.

In short, a profile is a list of limits for a given user. Some affect the password (livetime, locktime etc), some affect the resources the user can use (max sessions, max io etc). Unfortunately, profiles can only be seen by administrators.

Now users: For some reasons users and schemas are the same thing in Oracle (at least that is my interpretation). So if you want to create a table, or a function, or just about anything, it is owned by a user.

You can grant access to the tables of one user to another user. This can become quickly quite messy in bigger systems, so people usually grant access to a role, and then grant this role to the relevant users. Think of a role as a bag of privileges.

N.B. Technically, users and roles live in the same system table `SYS.USER$`, users have `type#=1`, roles `type#=0`. You can therefore think of roles as kind of castrated users that are not allowed to have any tables or other objects, but who's purpose in life is to have privileges and convey them to real users.

EDIT:

There is a list of available profiles in the data dictionary view `DBA_PROFILES`. Every user in the database is assigned to one of those profiles. I use the example database from [oracle vagrant](https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes/tree/master/OracleDatabase), there all users have the profile `DEFAULT`:

```
SELECT username, profile FROM DBA_USERS;
SYS     DEFAULT
SYSTEM  DEFAULT
...
```

A user can be granted zero or many roles. To make it worse, a role can be granted to another role (although some people discourage nested roles). So each user could have a whole tree of roles. Normally, it's just a list of less than a dozen roles.

Here is a list of all available roles:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLES;
CONNECT
RESOURCE
DBA
...
```

And here is a list of which user is granted what role:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS; 
SYS     DBA
SYS     AUDIT_ADMIN
SYS     CONNECT
SYSTEM  DBA
...
```

So profiles and roles are totally differnt things. Profiles regulate a users's password life and his/her connection to the database. Roles regulate which privileges (access to tables or system privileges) a user has.

Comment: This is great stuff, thanks a lot. But to double-check, one user can have a profile and a role?